# Update the intended participant descriptions for Area 51 sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

I noticed today that Area 51 and the Unix and Linux beta have slightly different descriptions of their intended participants.

The site page for [Unix and Linux on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux) says that it's a "Beta Q&A site for for advanced users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems."

The [FAQ on the Unix and Linux beta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) says that it's is "for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems."

Dropping the word "advanced" from the site description was [discussed on Unix and Linux meta site](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/can-we-get-rid-of-the-for-advanced-users-part-of-our-description) which seems to have been why it was removed from there.

I don't know if any of the other beta sites have made similar changes, but I was wondering if this sort of thing ought to be reflected on Area 51? Maybe edit permission could be given to the moderators pro tempore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not necessary to reflect this on Area 51, since the site is already launched and public..

Comment: People may browse area 51 to find stackexchange sites they are interested in. If the area 51 description says "for advanced users", potential users might never visit the site because they think it's not for them.